# How to tell pylint that sub-classes of a composed class have access to the parent members?

Tags: python, pylint

I have this test script:

```
class HugeGetterClass:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def getMe(self, key):
        return self._cache.get(key)

class HugeSetterClass:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def setMe(self, key, value):
        self._cache[key] = value

class ContainerClass(HugeGetterClass, HugeSetterClass):

    def __init__(self):
        HugeGetterClass.__init__(self)
        HugeSetterClass.__init__(self)
        self._cache = { }

a = ContainerClass()

a.setMe('a', 'Hello')
print a.getMe('a')
```

This is maybe not very good style, but works: `HugeGetterClass` and `HugeSetterClass` have access to `self._cache` indirectly, by being part of `ContainerClass`. But running `pylint` gives:

```
» pylint -E composing.py
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module composing
E:  7,15:HugeGetterClass.getMe: Instance of 'HugeGetterClass' has no '_cache' member
E: 15,8:HugeSetterClass.setMe: Instance of 'HugeSetterClass' has no '_cache' member
```

Which is understandable, but it annoys me. The classes have no `_cache` member, but have anyway access to it. I have several questions:

1. Is it possible to trick `pylint` on this, without disabling the error class completely, which is too heavy handed?
2. Is this coding style *pythonic*?. If not, what would the alternative way to code a huge class? What I am doing is separating functionality in sub-classes (in order to avoid having huge source files which become unmanageable), even though those subclasses are meant to be always used together.

Comment: I don't think it's Pythonic (I would never separate setters and getters of the same attribute), you should use @property for getters and setters, and why do you have such huge classes in the first place? But those things are off topic on Stack Overflow and should be discussed on the Code Review Stack Exchange instead.

Comment: That was just an example. I am not concerned about getters / setters, but about the generic idea of having subclasses access implicitly members of the top class. My huge class has grown out of encapsulating lots of functionality to access my datastore in CouchDB, including memcaching, bulk access, document filtering, attachments handling, url generation, lots of views, and more. But as you said this is not the main topic. Instead, I want to tell pylint to obviate the problem. Is this possible?

Comment: What about replacing your `pass`statements with `self._cache = {}`?

Comment: @Vincent: in my real code there are a dozen members which need to be accessed. I do not want to duplicate that code, and each sub-class needs access to a different set of members. It is not always a simple initialization like my cache example: sometimes depends on init parameters (`server`, `database`, ...), which I do not want to pass around just for the sake of avoiding this pylint error.

Comment: This isn't subclasses having implicit access to superclass members; this is superclasses having implicit access to subclass members. This is like having Person multiple-inherit from Head, Torso, Arms, and Legs. This doesn't look like a useful way to modularize your code. Consider the possibility that this class may be responsible for too much; don't write a [god object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you cannot instantiate and use properly `HugeGetterClass` and `HugeSetterClass` on their own because of the missing `_cache` attribute. This is why I suggested you to replace your `pass` statements with `self._cache = {}`. It's not just about patching the pylint error, it is also about making your code more pythonic and modulable.

Anyway, if you don't want these classes to be instantiable, Python has a tool for that : [ABC (Abstract Base Classes)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html).
This allows you to define base classes with abstract methods and properties.

Here's a simple example of what you're trying to achieve using an abc:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractproperty

class HugeGetterClass:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def get_me(self, key):
        return self.cache_access.get(key)

    @abstractproperty
    def cache_access(self):
        return {}

class ContainerClass(HugeGetterClass):

    def __init__(self):
        HugeGetterClass.__init__(self)
        self._cache = {"a":"Hello"}

    @property
    def cache_access(self):
        return self._cache

a = ContainerClass()
print a.get_me('a')
```